# How to create dynamic content in a web page according to the option selected in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a webpage where i have a dropdown menu with default option not selected. When the user selects an option then i want display textboxes related to that option. How can i do this. For example i have these images[image]

[image]

Comment: did you google for any solution? it is one of the easiest things in front-end issues with js

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on how many options you have in the list box and if the textboxes are shared between the options.

You could created hidden DIVs which are then shown when an option is selected. You would need to create a JavaScript function which is fired using the onChange event attached to the drop down.

If you were sharing the textboxes then given them specific classes which you can show/hide in the Javascript function, this is relatively simple if you use something like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for selection changed like so:

```
$('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $('#yourSelectId option:selected').attr('value');  
});
```

Then make some hidden divs visible depending on the selected value( $.('.class').hide() ).

Answer (score 0):

Use divs whose visibility is set to be hidden, and make it visible on select event. You can use multiple divs for atheistic purpose, associated with a select event.

An example can be found in post 2 at -

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=167172

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. All textboxes are hidden and with an event on your dropdown menu, you just show the right div.

HTML :

```
<select id='dropdown' onchange='showDiv()'>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="div1">Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Div 2</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<div id="div1" style='display: none;'>Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" style='display: none;'>Div 2</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
        var div = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
        if(document.getElementById(div) != null) {
        hideAllDiv();
            document.getElementById(div).style.display = "block";
    }
    }

    function hideAllDiv() {
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

The code above is ugly but you can do it better with jquery and some css.

*Edit :*

**Example with Jquery**

```
<select id='dropdown'>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option value="div1">Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Div 2</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<div class='div' id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div class='div' id="div2">Div 2</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .div { display: none; }
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dropdown").change(function() {
            $(".div").hide();
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```